# Concluding critical points of function are not in the domain for $f(x,y) = x^{3} - x +y^2 - 2y$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

My question has to do more with determining if the points are in the domain or not. So I am asked to find the extrema of the function $f(x,y) = x^{3} - x +y^2 - 2y$ over the closed trinagular region $(-1,0), (1,0), (0,2)$.

Taking the necessary derivatives I find the following "critical points"

$$\left(\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}},1\right)$$

Now a solution I have says "it is easy to conclude that the two points are not in the domain". My question is how is this conclusion drawn?

One way I wanted to know if it was correct was if I took the equation of the line between $(-1,0)$ and $(0,2)$ which is $y = 2x + 2$. If I plug my $x$ value from my critical point I don't get the corresponding $y$ value (in this case 1). Would that be the way to verify the points are not in the domain or is there another method to go about things?

Comment: Seems like you’re missing an exponent on one of the $y$s in the definition of the function.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is fine.

We can say that the triangle is bounded by the lines

$y = 2x + 2, y = -2x + 2, x = 0$

or the region is below the line

$y = \begin {cases} 2x + 2 & x\le 0\\ -2x + 2 & x>0\end{cases}$

Plugging the points $x = \pm \sqrt {\frac 13} \approx \pm\frac {4}{7}$

In fact $\frac {4}{7}$ is sligthly less than $\sqrt {\frac 13}$

$y(\sqrt {\frac 13}) < y(\frac 47) = \frac 67   < 1 $

The line is below the point $(\sqrt {\frac 13}, 1)$

Once you have found that there are no critical points inside the boundary, we must assume that the extrema lie on the boundary.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.